# getPublicKey is not a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, public-key, secp256k1

I'm trying to generate public key from private key using secp256k1, but I'm getting error saying: getPublicKey is not a function

```
const { getPublicKey, ecdsaSign } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");

 function _getPublicKey(_privateKey) {
    return getPublicKey(_privateKey);
  }

 const accountOnePublicKey = _getPublicKey(accountOnePrivateKey);
```

TypeError: getPublicKey is not a function
at _getPublicKey (/home/shubh/Desktop/my_crypto-wallet/newacc.js:84:12)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");

function _getPublicKey(_privateKey) {
    return secp256k1.getPublicKey(_privateKey);
}

const privateKey = "6b911fd37cdf5c81d4c0adb1ab7fa822ed253ab0ad9aa18d77257c88b29b718e";
const accountOnePublicKey = _getPublicKey(privateKey);
console.log(accountOnePublicKey, 'accountOnePublicKey');
```